# Importing lists to site collection from a .wsp file

Tags: sharepoint-online, solution-package

I have created a few lists in an empty site collection, now I would like to save/export this site collection (So I went to the site settings, and exported the site collection under "Site Actions" into a file called "myLists.wsp").

I imported "myLists.wsp" to another site collection to retrieve those lists.

Issue: The file "myLists.wsp" was successfully imported to the Solutions Gallery, and it has been successfully activated, but the lists were not imported.

Am I doing something wrong? Or am I still missing an option?

P.S: Unless I am wrong, I don't want to create a SharePoint project in Visual Studio for this since all I need is to import Content Types, Columns & Lists.

Thanks.

Comment: Save the lists as templates (stp files) and create a powershell script to upload them in the list library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After activation, You have to create site and while creating site you need to select the template which you have activated earlier.
In newly created site you will find the lists.

But if you want only lists to be created then you need to follow following steps.

1.Go to the List settings.

2.Click "Save list as a template".(Give proper name)

3.Download the List template.(Go to Site settings->List Templates)

4.Upload the downloaded List template(stp file) to where you want to create Lists

5.Now you can create List.You will find this template once you click on "Add an app" on site contents page

Repeat above steps for all Lists which you want to export to another site.

Comment: Thank you for the steps, it's disappointing I have to do this manually for each list though! I was hoping the .wsp file would work for the site collection.